# Appium driver has no WEBVIEW context

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

I'm writing Appium test for Chrome browser running on real Android Device.
 This code :

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName: contextNames) {
    System.out.println(contextName);
}
```

...returns only NATIVE_APP and CHROMIUM context, what is missing to enable WEBVIEW ? 
Or at least, can you specify who is in charge to provide Context?
Thanks!

Appium 1.7.1 / Selenium / Java

```
public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> capabilities() throws MalformedURLException

{
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>  driver;
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Device");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");

    driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    return driver;
}
```

Comment: latest version of chromium or latest version of android  even webview is show native elements, which version of android device are use using ?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 7.0

Comment: yes, IF you are using android 7.0 you no need to switch context, you can write native scripts

Answer (score 0):

Update the **Android System WebView** of your Android device through PlayStore.

With new UIautomator you don't need to switch your driver to webview. It has built in capabilities to identify the elements inside webView.

And also you can see the elements inside webView on Android 6.0+ devices using UIAutomator in the same way as you see the native elements.